# How was the rotation direction decided for single engine propeller craft?

Tags: propeller, single-engine

Spitfire, FW-190, Ki-43... was it selected arbitrarily to spin counter-clockwise?

Comment: The rotation was decided by the engine manufacturers.

Comment: And they didn't always agree... For example, the Genet Major radial engine installed in the C.30 Cierva Autogiro spun 'the other way', counterclockwise as seen by anyone in the propwash...  Another example is the Hispano Aviación HA-1112, a Spanish-built Bf 109 fitted with a Hispano-Suiza engine...

Comment: Maybe this was not "decided" at all.